# Statelessness of JWT and the definition of state

Tags: jwt

I have read quite a bit about JWT. I understand that using JWT, you do not need a central database to check tokens against, which is great. However, do we not need to securely store the JWT secret key in different services in sync? Why is this not considered "state" (albeit a much smaller one than a token database)?

Comment: The secret key is more of a server/application configuration, not a (client) state information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the secret key is static, it doesn't change regularly. The main problem of stateful applications is that you have to sync the state between your app server instances (for example through a database, as you said), which has the potential to create a big bottleneck. With the secret, you can just have it in a text file which exists on every server instance and not worry about having it synchronized between servers.